# React-Native:-How to give image for different resolution of android in single directory

Tags: android, ios, image, reactjs, react-native

I have kept image in single folder for both iOS and Android
Currently i have given image name like below

```
//For iOS
imagename.@2x.png
imagename.@3x.png

//For android
imagename.android.png
```

but here i am able to give only one image for android
I want to give different image for different resolution like mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi in same folder where i have kept image for iOS.

please provide me solution.

Answer (score 1):

The same is used for android version in React Native.

Comment: I am not getting, could you please give me an example?
what should I write for xxhdpi?

Comment: In your images you folder you have something like this

```imagename@2x.png, imagename@3x.png ```

When you include it in your project. Just include it as ```<Image src="/pathname.imagename" />``` Don't type in 2x, 3x etc. React Native will automatically put the correct image according to the dimensions of the device the app is being viewed in.

If this answer is correct, can you kindly mark it as correct. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

For specific to android and ios you can use specific ios and android assets structure as mentioned in react document below:-

```
Images From Hybrid App's Resources
If you are building a hybrid app (some UIs in React Native, some UIs in platform code) you can still use images that are already bundled into the app.

For images included via Xcode asset catalogs or in the Android drawable folder, use the image name without the extension:

<Image source={{uri: 'app_icon'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
For images in the Android assets folder, use the asset:/ scheme:

<Image source={{uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
These approaches provide no safety checks. It's up to you to guarantee that those images are available in the application. Also you have to specify image dimensions manually.
```